# Make in Windows

Tags: c, windows, makefile

I'm starting to learn C, I'm follwing the Learn C The Hard Way, in the [Exercise 1:](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html) it uses the command `make` in the shell, since I'm using windows I tried the same on the command line, but I got:

> make is not recognized as an internal or external command

After a bit of search I found [Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm). Which works, but in the section **How To Break It**, it uses `CFLAGS="-Wall" make ex1`. it doesn't work on the command, I tried making a make file in the folder, but it seems to ignore it and outputs:

```
cc "-Wall" make ex1.c    ex1.c   -o ex1
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:make: file
format not recognized; treating as linker script
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:make:1: syn
tax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ex1] Error 1
```

Where it should be:

> cc -Wall    ex1.c   -o ex1

How can I set makefile in the folder in windows?

Here's my makefile:

```
CFLAGS="-Wall" make ex1
```

---

Turns out that that the makefile should be:

```
CFLAGS= -Wall
```

But in the next exercise it uses `make clean`

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g
clean:
    rm  -f  ex1
```

output this:

```
rm ex1
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm ex1, ...) failed.
make (e=2) the system cannot find the file specified
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Comment: Try with `ex1.exe`. Eventually you may find that it's more convenient to learn C under GNU/Linux. If you have relatively decent hardware, then you might work on some VM.

Comment: The examples aren't written with a Windows console in mind.  You could try installing Msys and use its shell, or setting up a linux system or virtual machine.  Otherwise you'd have to understand what the commands in the examples do so you can adapt them for the Windows console.  (`CFLAGS="-Wall" make ...` is trying to set an environment variable `CFLAGS` to the string `-Wall` while running `make`)

Comment: `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm ex1, ...) failed.` is equivalent to `make is not recognized as an internal or external command`. Essentially that is Windows telling you that command doesn't exist either.